# C# Rider How to disable format/reformat in a block of code?

Tags: c#, rider

I've got some C# code that has specific format that I don't want re-formatted by Rider.

Is there some directive I can add to my code to tell Rider that this section shouldn't be reformatted?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To disable auto formatting for some code block you can use [`formatter` directive](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/11/27/different-code-styles-different-code-blocks-resharper-rider/):

```
// @formatter:off

some custom formatted code that should be kept as is.
   
// @formatter:on
```

Possibly you will need to enable it in settings: Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Formatter Control tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `.editorconfig` to your project to customize the formatting behavior. 
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_EditorConfig.html

Comment: I assume that OP is asking about some specific code block which should keep different formatting to the rest of the code.